# Promitor scraper metrics for Azure file storage not reflecting in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am not able to getting azure file storage metrics , Azure file storage is not reflecting in Prometheus graph

-> Promitor Scraper and Promitor agent resouce discovery using for getting Azure resources metrics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZkWp.png)

Above is the one metrics example tried with Multiple queries

Expecting : To fetch the Azure file storage  metrics

2. Collecting File Share and Blob details metrics .